# Creating HTML forms dynamically in a vertical column

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps, html

So I have this code that will create a new form input field, it is inside a javascript method that fires on each mouse click within a Google Maps window. Right now it is creating each form on a single line, how would I get each new form to show up below the previous one?

Thanks for any help!

JavaScript:

```
//Creates new input boxes for each new marker
var newForm = "Checkpoint " + markerId + " Name:<input type='text' id=" + markerId + " />";
document.getElementById("divForms").innerHTML = document.getElementById("divForms").innerHTML + newForm;
```

HTML:

```
<form id="divForms"></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the line break tag `<br />` to the end of `newform`:

```
var newForm = "Checkpoint " + markerId + " Name:<input type='text' id=" + markerId + " /><br />";
```

Or when assigning the `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("divForms").innerHTML = document.getElementById("divForms").innerHTML + '<br />' + newForm;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying "\n", I'm not very familiar with HTML.